# How to get valid json resp from Flask app with jsonapi version 1.0, "Content-type"="application/vnd.api+json"

Tags: python, json, flask

I have failed to get any resp from the code below. I have tried different "Content-type", tried building my json in all different ways possible. Please help.

```
@app.route('/api/v1/client', methods={'GET', 'POST'})
def client():
 if request=='post':
     req = request.get_data()
     data = req.json
     user_id = data["data"]["attributes"]["user_id"]
     redirect_uri = data["data"]["attributes"]["_redirect_uris"]
     default_scopes = data["data"]["attributes"]["_default_scopes"]

     item = Client(
         client_id=gen_salt(40),
         client_secret=gen_salt(55),

         _redirect_uris=' '.join(redirect_uri),
         _default_scopes=' '.join(default_scopes),
         user_id=user_id,

         allowed_grant_types=' '.join(['implicit', ]),
         allowd_response_types=' '.join(['token', ])
         )

     db.session.add(item)
     db.session.commit()

     resp = {
         "data":{
             "attributes":{
                 "client_id" : "client id",
                 "client_secret" : "client_secret"
             },
         "jsonapi":{
             "version" : "1.0"
             },
         "type":"client"
         }
     }

     resp["data"]["attributes"]["client_id"] = item.client_id
     resp["data"]["attributes"]["client_secret"]= item.client_secret
     status = 200

     return (jsonify(resp), status, {"Content-type":"application/vnd.api+json"})
```

Please, help me! I must be doing something entirely wrong. But a very similar code is working in another function. 
The error which I am getting is "ValueError: View function did not return a response // Werkzeug Debugger".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to check if the request was sent via POST, you should use `if request.method == 'POST':` instead of `if request == 'POST':`.

And if you want to get JSON body of the request, you should use `request.get_json()`.

The rest of your work seems fine, but I'd recommend you to read full Flask documentation before doing something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I was passing json (jsonapi v1,0) as raw string in POST request (Some requirement as rest of the API had been written with Flask-restless which needed json in that format;and I wanted entire API to be consistent); hence could not use get_json(). And, as we need to read POST body before returning any response, I was getting empty response and hence above error.
Got it ticking with: 
/req = request.get_data()/ 
/data = json.loads(req)/

thanks for the request.method, I had totally over looked it.